# Rails 5.1.6 AWS Elastic Beanstalk Yarn / Node JS Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services

Having issue with app deploy since upgrading AWS Ruby environment versions.

This is the error i am receiving when deploying my application:

```
Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
rake aborted!
Autoprefixer doesn’t support Node v4.6.0. Update it.
/var/app/ondeck/vendor/bundle/gems/autoprefixer-rails-9.1.3/lib/autoprefixer-rails/processor.rb:163:in `runtime' 
....
```

This is the version i'm using of Elastic Beanstalk. 
`Puma with Ruby 2.5 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.8.4`

Any ideas?

I've setup an Elastic Beanstalk Config file to Install Yarn/Node. But doesnt seem to fix the error. (Found this in a React on Rails thread).

```
container_commands:
  01_node_get:
    cwd: /tmp
    command: 'sudo curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo bash -'
  02_node_install:
    cwd: /tmp
    command: 'sudo yum -y install nodejs'
  03_yarn_get:
    cwd: /tmp
    # don't run the command if yarn is already installed (file /usr/bin/yarn exists)
    test: '[ ! -f /usr/bin/yarn ] && echo "yarn not installed"'
    command: 'sudo wget https://dl.yarnpkg.com/rpm/yarn.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/yarn.repo'
  04_yarn_install:
    cwd: /tmp
    test: '[ ! -f /usr/bin/yarn ] && echo "yarn not installed"'
    command: 'sudo yum -y install yarn'
```

Upgrade to Rails 5.2. Same issue present. Tried Puma with Ruby 2.5 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.6.0. same issue.

Answer (score 4):

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands:

> Container commands run after the application and web server have been set up and the application version archive has been extracted, but before the application version is deployed.

Instead use [Commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-commands):

> The commands run before the application and web server are set up and the application version file is extracted.

E.g

```
commands:
  01_node_get:
    # run this command from /tmp directory
    cwd: /tmp
    # flag -y for no-interaction installation (visit https://rpm.nodesource.com for latest)
    command: 'curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | sudo bash -'

  02_node_install:
    # run this command from /tmp directory
    cwd: /tmp
    command: 'sudo yum -y install nodejs'

  03_yarn_get:
    # run this command from /tmp directory
    cwd: /tmp
    # don't run the command if yarn is already installed (file /usr/bin/yarn exists)
    test: '[ ! -f /usr/bin/yarn ] && echo "yarn not installed"'
    command: 'sudo wget https://dl.yarnpkg.com/rpm/yarn.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/yarn.repo'

  04_yarn_install:
    # run this command from /tmp directory
    cwd: /tmp
    test: '[ ! -f /usr/bin/yarn ] && echo "yarn not installed"'
    command: 'sudo yum -y install yarn'
```

Comment: Updated node install commands:
`sudo yum install https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_16.x/nodistro/repo/nodesource-release-nodistro-1.noarch.rpm -y` and `sudo yum install nodejs -y --setopt=nodesource-nodejs.module_hotfixes=1`. See https://github.com/nodesource/distributions